# Jumpseller category dropdown menu won't work in navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I have absolutely no experience with html. I have a pre-made e-commerce webpage with Jumpseller.

http://www.wofdelivery.cl

The dropdown menu "productos" won't display. You only can click "productos" and go to thay specific page.

This is the "code" for the navigation menu.

```
<li class="nav-item {% if item.dropdown %}dropdown{% endif %} {% if active_items contains item.id %}active{% endif %}">
  <a href="{{ item.url }}" {% if item.external %}target="_blank"{% endif %} title="{{item.name}}" class="{% if item.dropdown%}dropdown-toggle {% endif %}level-1 nav-link" {% if item.dropdown %}data-toggle=""{% endif %}>{{ item.name }}</a>
  {% if item.dropdown %}
    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
      {% for item in item.items %}
        {% include 'navigation_menu' with item %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
</li>
```

This is the code for the home page were the dropdown menu "productos" is.

```
<!-- Slider Section-->
{% include 'slider_home' %}

<!-- Features Section -->
{% include 'features_home' %}

<div class="container principal">
  <!-- Banners Section -->
  {% include 'banners_home' %}

  {% case options.products_home %}
  {% when "featured-home" or "latest-and-featured-home"  %}
  <!-- Featured Products Section -->
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="col-12"><h2 class="section-title">{% t 'Featured Products' %}</h2></div>
    {% if products.all == empty %}
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      {% assign placeholders = "1,2,3,4" | split: "," %}
      {% for placeholder in placeholders %}
      <div class="no-product item">
        <div class="product-block">
          <div style="background-image: url('{{ 'no-image-home.png' | asset }}');"></div>
          <div class="caption">
            <a href="{{store.url}}/admin/products/new" class="butn">{% t 'Add products' %}</a>
            <span class="product-block-list">$0.00</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {%else%}
    <!-- Featured Products -->
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      {% for product in products.featured limit:options.products_featured_limit %}
      <div class="item">
        {% include 'list_product' with product %}
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  {% when "latest-home" or "latest-and-featured-home" %}
  <!-- Latest Products Section -->
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="col-12"><h2 class="section-title">{% t 'Latest Products' %}</h2></div>
    {% if products.all == empty %}
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      {% assign placeholders = "1,2,3,4" | split: "," %}
      {% for placeholder in placeholders %}
      <div class="no-product item">
        <div class="product-block">
          <a href="{{store.url}}/admin/products/new" class="product-image">
            <div style="background-image: url('{{ 'no-image-home.png' | asset }}');"></div>
          </a>
          <div class="caption">
            <a href="{{store.url}}/admin/products/new" class="butn butn-block">{% t 'Add products' %}</a>
            <div class="list-price mt-2">
              <span class="product-block-list">$0.00</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {%else%}
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      {% for product in products.latest limit:options.products_home_limit %}
      <div class="item">
        {% include 'list_product' with product %}
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>

  {% when "not-display"%}

  {% endcase%}

  {% if options.featured_category_home_1 != blank %}
  <!-- Category Products Carousel Section 1 -->
  {% assign cat = store.category[options.featured_category_home_1] %}
  {% if cat.products.count != 0 %}
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="col-12"><h2 class="section-title">{{ cat.name }}</h2></div>
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      {% for product in cat.products  %}
      <div class="item">
        {% include 'list_product' with product %}
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 button-footer">
      <a href="{{ cat.url }}" title="View all {{ cat.name }}" class="butn">{% t 'View all' %}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endif %}


  {% if options.featured_category_home_2 != blank%}
  <!-- Category Products Carousel Section 2 -->
  {% assign cat = store.category[options.featured_category_home_2] %}
  {% if cat.products.count != 0 %}
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="col-12"><h2 class="section-title">{{ cat.name }}</h2></div>
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      {% for product in cat.products  %}
      <div class="item">
        {% include 'list_product' with product %}
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 button-footer">
      <a href="{{ cat.url }}" title="View all {{ cat.name }}" class="butn">{% t 'View all' %}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if options.featured_category_home_3 != blank%}
  <!-- Category Products Carousel Section 3 -->
  {% assign cat = store.category[options.featured_category_home_3] %}
  {% if cat.products.count != 0 %}
  <div class="row section">
    <div class="col-12"><h2 class="section-title">{{ cat.name }}</h2></div>
    <div class="owl-carousel">
      {% for product in cat.products  %}
      <div class="item">
        {% include 'list_product' with product %}
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 button-footer">
      <a href="{{ cat.url }}" title="View all {{ cat.name }}" class="butn">{% t 'View all' %}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if options.home_page_blog %}
  <!-- Blog Home -->
  <div id="blog-list" class="row section">
    <div class="col-12"><h2 class="section-title">{% t 'Blog' %}</h2></div>
    {% unless pages.categories.category["Post"] == blank %}
    {% paginate pages.categories.category["Post"].pages by options.page_post_per_page reversed %}

    {% for page in paged.pages reversed %}
    {% if forloop.index0 == 4 %}{% break %}{% endif %}
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-12">
      <div class="row block-post no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
          <a href="{{ page.url }}" title="{{ page.title }}" class="butn wi"><i class='linear-icon icon-0166-eye'></i>{% t 'Read More' %}</a>
          <a href="{{ page.url }}" title="{{ page.title }}">
            {% if page.images == empty %}
            <div class="blog-image" style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/320x275')"></div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="blog-image" style="background-image: url('{{ page.images.first }}')"></div>
            {% endif %}
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
          <div class="inner">
            <a href="{{ page.url }}" title="{{ page.title }}"><h3>{{ page.title }}</h3></a>
            {% if page.body != blank%}<p>{{ page.body | strip_html | truncate: 210 }}</p>{% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="col-12 button-footer">
      <a href="blog" title="Blog" class="butn">{% t 'Go to Blog' %}</a>
      {% endpaginate %}
      {% endunless %}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>

{% if options.instafeed and social.instagram_url != blank %}
<!-- Instagram widget -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"><h2 class="section-title">Instagram</h2></div>
    <div id="instagram" class="col-12 limit-{{ options.instagram-limit }}">
      {% capture follow_us_translation %}{% t "Follow Us" %}{% endcapture %}
      <span><a href="{{ social.instagram_url }}" target="_blank" title="{{follow_us_translation}} @{{ social.instagram_url | split: '/' | last }}" class="butn"><i class="fab fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ follow_us_translation }}</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Instagram code -->
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: "/instagram-app/media",
 data: {
 count: {% if options.instagram-limit %}{{ options.instagram-limit }}{% else %}10{% endif %}
 },
   success: function(json) {
   for (var i in json.posts) {
  if(i >= {% if options.instagram-limit %}{{ options.instagram-limit }}{% else %}10{% endif %}){continue};
        url = json.posts[i].thumbnail_url;
        shortcode = json.posts[i].shortcode;

        newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.className = 'insta_img';
        newElement.style = 'background-image: url(' + url + ')';

 newElementLink = document.createElement('a');
  newElementLink.href = json.posts[i].permalink;
  newElementLink.target = "_blank";
      newElementLink.appendChild(newElement);

      var clientHeight = document.getElementById('instagram').clientHeight;
      document.getElementById("instagram").appendChild(newElementLink);
    }
  }
  });
</script>
{% endif %}

<script>
  function parse_str(str) {
    return str.split('&').reduce(function(params, param) {
      var paramSplit = param.split('=').map(function(value) {
        return decodeURIComponent(value.replace('+', ' '));
      });
      params[paramSplit[0]] = paramSplit[1];
      return params;
    }, {});
  }
</script>

></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu item with products contains a link, clicking on which you go to another page, so it is more logical to display the dropdown menu by hovering the mouse cursor. I made this rule for you. Just paste it into your styles, inside the `<style>...</style>` tag. If you have any difficulties, then refer here in the comments.

```
.nav-item.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu.multi-level {
   display: block;
}
```